# how boolean works in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean

I don't understand how boolean works.In the following example what is the necessity of the line "var check=false" and how does it work?/when should I use them?what if I write "var check=true" instead??

```
var hits=[];
for(var n=2;n<101;n++){
    var check=false;
    for(var i=2;i<=9;i++){
        if(n%i===0 && n!=i)
            check=true;
    }
    if(check===false){
        hits.push(n);
    }
}
```

please explain boolean a bit .I'm stuck here

Comment: A boolean is a value that's either `true` or `false`.  That's pretty much all there is to it.  The necessity of that particular line is to declare the variable and assign it an initial value.  That doesn't have much to do with the fact that it's a boolean or even the fact that this is JavaScript.  Declaring a variable is a very fundamental concept for many programming languages.

Comment: Try following the code execution with pen and paper. This is pretty trivial stuff. Not sure what there is to say about booleans specifically in this code.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean datatype is a 1-bit datatype that can either be set to "true" or "false".  It is sometimes referred to as a flag variable to check if a certain condition is true.

In javascript, when you declare a variable, you can set it to any datatype, so saying `var check=false;` sets a variable check to the condition false.

All `if()` statements and `while()` statements check a boolean expression to see if that code will run or not.

So, after you declare check, if you said

```
if(check){...}
```

that code wouldn't run because check is false.

Hope this helps